# React MUI 4 SelectInput.js:340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This error happens when you provide an empty array as `options`.

The error log:

```js
SelectInput.js:340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at SelectInput.js:340:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SelectInput.js:339:1
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22269:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327:1
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23620:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:23324:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:417:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:390:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:157:1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case my component looked like this. You should focus on the `options` part only thought.

```js
<FormControl error={error}>
  <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    label={label}
  >
    {
      options.length &&
        options.map((option, i) => {
          return (<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} key={i} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>)
        })
      }
  </Select>
  { error && <FormHelperText>{ helperText }</FormHelperText> }
</FormControl>
```

When I changed my component to look like this

```js
<FormControl error={error}>
  <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    label={label}
  >
    {
      // --> Notice below changes
      options.length > 0 && // --> Changes from `options.length ? ...` to `options.length > 0 && ...`
        options.map((option, i) => {
          return (<MenuItem className={classes.menuItem} key={i} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>)
        })
      }
  </Select>
  { error && <FormHelperText>{ helperText }</FormHelperText> }
</FormControl>
```

And then it didn't happen again.

**If you want longer explanation**, the error log was referring to `InputJS:340:1` which refers to the following line

```js
React.useEffect(function () {
  if (!foundMatch && !multiple && value !== '') {
    var values = childrenArray.map(function (child) {
      return child.props.value; // ---> This line specifically
    });
    console.warn(["Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `".concat(value, "` for the select ").concat(name ? "(name=\"".concat(name, "\") ") : '', "component."), "Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.", "The available values are ".concat(values.filter(function (x) {
      return x != null;
    }).map(function (x) {
      return "`".concat(x, "`");
    }).join(', ') || '""', ".")].join('\n'));
  }
}, [foundMatch, childrenArray, multiple, name, value]);
```

Let's just say the `options.length ? ...` conditional lets the "whatever value" slip through while `SelectInput.js` **was expecting for it to be an array of children**, but instead of getting an array, it's getting that "whatever value".

That's why when `child.props.value` was expecting a transformed value, it resulted in `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. Because the `child` probably doesn't even have `props` value defined.